# formtastic and bootstrap compatibility

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, formtastic

are all the formtastic input types supposed to work when using the gem 'formtastic-bootstrap' ?

in my case :

```
 :as => :select
```

is working fine

but

```
:as => :date_select
```

gives Formtastic::UnknownInputError

and

```
:as => :radio
```

is displaying indeed radio button but mixed with black dots (such as in a webpage with no css )  !?

my gemfile contains :

```
gem 'formtastic', " ~> 2.1.1"
gem 'formtastic-bootstrap'
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
```

my layouts/application.html.erb

```
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have better luck with a newer version of formtastic-bootstrap.

Support for :date_select has been [added recently](https://github.com/kristianmandrup/formtastic-bootstrap/commit/45252a759b8d5ff4eb875dfcc74fe020c3d22cdf) and formtastic-bootstrap 2.0.0 supports :date_select.